# What routes do I add so I can have mixed MVC and Web API with both default Get and additional actions?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am construction a mixed asp.net app that has an mvc controller and a web api controller. I read the docs but I cannot get the web api controllers default get to match.

Here are my mapped routes:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "api default",
                template: "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "api actions",
                template: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });
```

Here's the action that won't match and returns HTTP 500:

```
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //EF Core statement that returns data is here

            return Ok(data);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
```

This one matches fine:

```
    [Route("ProjectRoles/{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult ProjectRoles(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //EF Core that gets data
            if (data == null)
                return NotFound(id);
            else
                return Ok(data.ProjectRoles);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: *returns HTTP 500* - What's the specific error?

Comment: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. So, why am I not allowed to have multiple Get's? I want an action named Chemicals and one named SubContractors and so forth.

Comment: Can you show your controller declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add additional routing in your startup.You could use MVC and Web Api controller together in asp.net core MVC project by default.Just create a new web api controller when you right-click the Controllers folder in vs.

The only thing is to configure attribute routing in your web api controller like

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ProjectRolesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/ProjectRoles
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/ProjectRoles/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```